# Desktop PC casing without side panel

Tags: desktop-computer

My desktop PC casing uses a tempered glass side panel. It has been accidentally broken. Now, my PC runs without a side panel. So far, it is running smoothly.

What are the risks and side effects of running a PC without a side panel? Will it shorten the lifespan and affect the reliability of my PC? What are things to watch out?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 risks -

1. Cooling may not be as effective because air may not be being forced across components correctly. Monitor your CPU temp to see if this is an issue
2. Dust. It's possible your case has filters for dust which would now be inoperative as air does not flow through them anymore. This is somewhat unlikely though and you can keep an eye on your CPU fan to see if it's getting dustier.

In any event, if there is a problem your computer will slow down until you fix whatever is causing heat not to dissipate - it won't damage the CPU because VPUs are designed to handle this.

Of-course, there is also an increased risk of physical damage as components are not protected by the case anymore.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Dust filter is at the top of the PC casing. So, I am not son concerned. I thought cooling would be better since there is no more enclosure with the open air? It's like a naked person should feel cooler. What are VPUs

Comment: Remember that air takes the path of least resistance - so the dust filter will become less efficient. Cooling might be better but probably will. Be worse, again because air is not being forced through the case in a specific flow.